# Shall we stop (or delay) our jobs when someone sneezes?

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-basis

Some people believe that you ought to stop you works(acts) whenever you or somebody else sneezes. For instance this matter has mentioned in the following site as well. ([www.asriran.com](http://www.asriran.com/fa/news/210029) )

(Of course I don’t know how much it is an authentic site. Anyhow I saw this matter in many other sites as well). Anyhow, some people believe that sneezing is the sign of patience and they believe that:

> If for instance somebody sneezes, you should stop your works, (you
>   should stop for some moments), then keep on your jobs, otherwise the
>   result of your job will be negative.

I was wondering if it is a truth or this is considered as a superstition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plain superstition. No evidence from the Quran and Sunnah to support such case.

However, one of the obligations of the Muslim is to perform [Tashmeet](http://sunnah.com/urn/2117560) (Him/Her saying Alhumiullah **`الحمد لله`**, you are saying Yahrhuka Allah **`يرحمكم الله`**, and he/she replying Yahdeekom Allah Wayoseleh balkom **`يهديكم الله ويصلح بالكلم`**)